# DrawerLayout modify sensitivity?

Tags: android, android-layout

The DrawerLayout default sensitivity is okay, but I would like to make it a little easier to do the left-to-right sliding gesture on the side of the screen to open the drawerlayout. I find it particiular difficult on tablets, but also on some phones.

I don't see any gesture or gesture controller references in the DrawerLayout page on the web API.. Has anyone seen something that will allow us to do this?

Answer (score 5):

For `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` I came up with a hack which allows you to expand the area where sliding gesture (stroke) can start, thus making sliding gesture easier.

**Hack implementation:**

```
    // assuming mDrawerLayout is an instance of android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    try {

        // get dragger responsible for the dragging of the left drawer
        Field draggerField = DrawerLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mLeftDragger");
        draggerField.setAccessible(true);
        ViewDragHelper vdh = (ViewDragHelper)draggerField.get(mDrawerLayout);

        // get access to the private field which defines
        // how far from the edge dragging can start
        Field edgeSizeField = ViewDragHelper.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeSize");
        edgeSizeField.setAccessible(true);

        // increase the edge size - while x2 should be good enough,
        // try bigger values to easily see the difference
        int origEdgeSize = (int)edgeSizeField.get(vdh);
        int newEdgeSize = (int) (origEdgeSize * 2); 
        edgeSizeField.setInt(vdh, newEdgeSize);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // we unexpectedly failed - e.g. if internal implementation of 
        // either ViewDragHelper or DrawerLayout changed
    }
```

**Explanation:**

The hack is based on the fact that DrawerLayout class relies on instances of [ViewDragHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html) to handle the dragging. There are two instances - one for the left drawer, and one for the right one. They are getting instantiated like this:

```
 public DrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    ... code omitted for brevity ..

    mLeftDragger = ViewDragHelper.create(this, TOUCH_SLOP_SENSITIVITY, mLeftCallback);
    mLeftDragger.setEdgeTrackingEnabled(ViewDragHelper.EDGE_LEFT);
    mLeftDragger.setMinVelocity(minVel);
    mLeftCallback.setDragger(mLeftDragger);

    mRightDragger = ViewDragHelper.create(this, TOUCH_SLOP_SENSITIVITY, mRightCallback);
    mRightDragger.setEdgeTrackingEnabled(ViewDragHelper.EDGE_RIGHT);
    mRightDragger.setMinVelocity(minVel);
    mRightCallback.setDragger(mRightDragger);

    ... code omitted for brevity ..
}
```

Both `mLeftDragger` and `mRightDragger` are private fields, and `mFieldSize` field in `ViewDragHelper` is also private. There are no public methods which would let client code to set those fields - hence the hack relies on the reflection, which is fragile towards internal implementation changes in ViewDragHelper and DrawerLayout classes.

**Bonus:**
[A comprehensive tutorial on ViewDragHelper usage](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/)

Comment: This still works. Is there some other way to do this that the developers anticipated? Why would you _not_ want to adjust the sensitivity of the drawer? On my Samsung S6 the margin was very small. It was nearly impossible to get the drawer to slide out if the phone was in a case.

Answer (score -1):

A simple gesture example : You can try to put on the top screen 2 images with circle , and when you pressed on the one to jump to another layer , and again you pressed the previous circle to jump again . Try to jump from one activity to another one and if you want to close the previous activity , after you called the next activity just close the previous one with .finish();